# Iterating multiple Outlook COM Object fails

Tags: powershell, outlook, com

We're having a very strange problem. When iterating through multiple elements in an array of public folder names, PowerShell sometimes throws an error. But not always.

When running the code below with as input only one element it works fine but when multiple elements are defined the second iteration throws an error.

According to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx) Microsoft article one should `Release` the `COM-Object`, but this doesn't work either.

**Code**

```
Param (
    [String]$Mail         = 'User@donain.com',
    [String]$ImportFile   = 'C:\Scripts\Import.txt'
)

$Import = Get-Content $ImportFile

$Start = "\\Public Folders - $Mail"
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook'

foreach ($L in $Import) {
    $PSTFile = "$ExportFolder\$($L -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9-_ \.\[\]]', ' ').pst"

    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application -Verbose:$false
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

    $AllPublicFolders = $Namespace.Folders | where FolderPath -EQ $Start | ForEach-Object {
        $Start = $Start + '\All Public Folders'
        $_.Folders | where FolderPath -EQ $Start
    }

    $Split = $L.Split('\')

    $Folder = Switch ($Split.Count) {
        1 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0])}
        2 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1])}
        3 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2])}
        4 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3])}
        5 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3]).Folders.Item($Split[4])}
        6 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3]).Folders.Item($Split[4]).Folders.Item($Split[5])}
        7 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3]).Folders.Item($Split[4]).Folders.Item($Split[5]).Folders.Item($Split[6])}
        8 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3]).Folders.Item($Split[4]).Folders.Item($Split[5]).Folders.Item($Split[6]).Folders.Item($Split[7])}
        9 {$AllPublicFolders.Folders.Item($Split[0]).Folders.Item($Split[1]).Folders.Item($Split[2]).Folders.Item($Split[3]).Folders.Item($Split[4]).Folders.Item($Split[5]).Folders.Item($Split[6]).Folders.Item($Split[7]).Folders.Item($Split[8])}
    }

    Write-Verbose "Folder '$($Folder.FolderPath.TrimStart($Start))'"

    Write-Verbose "Add PST"
    $NameSpace.AddStore($PSTFile)
    $PSTStore = $NameSpace.Stores | where {$_.FilePath -eq $PSTFile}

    Write-Verbose "Copy content to PST"
    $Folder.CopyTo($PSTStore) | Out-Null

    Write-Verbose "Remove PST"
    $PST = $NameSpace.Stores | where {$_.FilePath -eq $PSTFile}
    $PSTRoot= $PST.GetRootFolder()
    $PSTFolder= $NameSpace.Folders.Item($PSTRoot.Name)
    $NameSpace.GetType().InvokeMember('RemoveStore',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$Namespace,($PSTFolder))

    $Outlook.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
    Remove-Variable Outlook

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
```

**ImportFile**

```
WEUR - COMPANY\DAF\Tableau de bord IB\Année 2002\07 juillet
WEUR - COMPANY\DAF\Tableau de bord IB\Année 2002\08 Août
```

**Error**

```
Failed for path 'WEUR - DOMAIM\DAF\Tableau de bord IB\Année 2002\08 Août': You cannot call a method on a null-va
lued expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:

```
$AllPublicFolders = $Namespace.Folders | where FolderPath -EQ "\\Public Folders - $Mail" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Folders | where FolderPath -EQ "\\Public Folders - $Mail\All Public Folders"
}
```